# Inverter Generator Watt Question

Tags: led, inverter, generator, watts

I'm not sure how to search this so hopefully someone will answer. I'm rigging a floundering boat for my son and want to use LED light bars on the front and sides. I want to power then with an inverter generator because they are so much lighter and quieter. The LED light bars are 12 VDC, the invertor generator is 2000 watts and has 2 receptacles for 110 VAC and one for 12 VDC. The LED light bars will total around 1200 watts at 12 VDC. Will the single, 12 VDC receptacle handle that many watts or is there another way I should power the LED light bars?

Comment: The 12 Vdc output on most of the generators I have seen is good for about 8 Amps or about 100 Watts. But look at either the spec sheet for your particular generator **or** look at the label on your generator.

Comment: 1.2kW of LEDs!?!? How big is this boat? There are LED streetlights which only require 100-300W. What kind of wire are you intending to use to handle the 100A current flowing?

Comment: The DC output of my Honda 2000 watt inverter-style generator is intended for battery charging only - not as a general DC supply.  Check the specs for your generator.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to look into more detail into your invertor. If the generator is rated at 2000w, then it can handle 1200; however, that rating might be for the AC output and not DC.

Check to see if it contains any rating specifically for the DC output. If you cannot find this, the invertor will probably be fused; if you can determine the value of the DC fuse then you can establish what wattage the invertor DC output was intended for.

Comment: Here is an ebay link to one of the LED light bars. I want to use 2 of these. Would I be better off using a 110 VAC to 12 VDC converter in the 110 receptacle? http://www.ebay.com/itm/42INCH-400W-PHILIPS-Curved-LED-Light-Bar-Flood-Spot-Combo-Offroad-Truck-4WD-480W-/261878097253?hash=item3cf926a565:g:GqkAAOSwwE5WX9r-&vxp=mtr

Comment: You will have to do that if your generator (12v) output cannot provide that power...do you have the generator model?